# Order BY SQL Short Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I would like to order by the short date

```
ShortDate

20-Nov
17-Nov
29-Nov
15-Nov
7-Nov
6-Dec
25-Nov
14-Nov
9-Nov
12-Nov
5-Dec
26-Nov
28-Nov
8-Nov
1-Dec
3-Dec
23-Nov
```

---

I used

```
ORDER BY CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,ShortDate) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(RIGHT( '0' + CAST(DAY(ShortDate) AS varchar(2)), 2) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS INT) DESC
```

the whole query is

```
SELECT  StaffAttendencecount  ,TC.ShortDate
FROM #TempStaffAttendnece  
INNER JOIN #TempCONStaffAttendnece TC
ON #TempStaffAttendnece.ShortDate = TC.ShortDate
ORDER BY CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,TC.ShortDate) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(RIGHT( '0' + CAST(DAY(TC.ShortDate) AS varchar(2)), 2) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS INT) DESC
```

but its not working
I get

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 80
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

can any one help

Comment: Please explain this: "but its not working". Also give us the whole query not only the order by part.

Comment: Why are you working with strings when every database system has built in `datetime` related data types that it already knows how to sort correctly? Ideally, keep it in such types as much as possible and only format it into text when displaying it to the user (Similarly, parse input text as early as possible - most of your application should be working with datetime datatypes, not strings, when processing dates)

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Date/time and string functions are both areas where many dbms products have their own versions.

Comment: It says Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 80
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @VBoka Added more details in the question

Comment: @De198 stil waiting for the column data type ?

Comment: @VBoka it was created by select into 

CAST(DATEPART(DAY,[LOG_TIME]) AS VARCHAR(50)) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,[LOG_TIME]),1,3) ShortDate

Comment: Hi @De198 and what is wrong with the answer provided ?

Answer (score 1):

You ideally should not be storing your dates as text, or, if you must, then try to use an ISO format which at least has the year, month, and day.  That being said, you could form a bona-fide here and then sort on that:

```sql
SELECT ShortDate
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(datetime, ShortDate + '-2020');
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

But, as mentioned above, you should view this query as a short term fix until you get a chance to fix your data model and convert the `ShortDate` column to a proper bona fide date or timestamp column.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 85
'LPAD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought you were using Oracle (you never tagged your question properly).  I have edited it for SQL Server, if that would help.